# How to open links within Iframe inside parent window without back button creating issues

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have an application that embeds iframe. Whenever a link is clicked in Iframe it navigates away from the parent. For example when iframe is loaded the browser url is *'https://localhost:4200/ui/#/adaptive-ip?url=abc/services/evpn'*. Now if I click on some link in iframe its target's href is *'/abc/analysis'* and it navigates to *'https://localhost:4200/abc/analysis'* which I don't want. I need that whenever a link in iframe is clicked the browser url should be *'https://localhost:4200/ui/#/adaptive-ip?url=abc/services/analysis'* and similar should be the target's href.
So for this I have captured the click event on iframe and did

```
target.href= adaptiveUrl
```

and for keeping browser url also in track with iframe i did export

```
function addBaseToIframe (iframe) {
  const baseElement = document.createElement('base')
  baseElement.target = '_parent'
  iframe.contents().find('head').append(baseElement)
}
```

Now doing this it works fine as expected but the problem arises when I click on back button of the browser. The browser url remains same though the iframe content is changed and when again clicked on back button iframe content remains same and browser url changed. I mean currently I need to click back button twice to get out of the current page.